# CSS3 webkit transitions

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have an image that can be clicked, causing another image to slide in above. You can then get the image to slide out again by clicking the animated image. This works fine. But I would actually like to slide the image from bottom to top rather than from left to right, however if I change the left property to top (see commented code) one of the transitions breaks. I know I could do this is JS, but I just want to know if it's possible to achieve this using only css. (I can get the vertical tween to work if I use hover rather than click, however I need click)! Thank you.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>images</title>

<style>

#container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#image {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}
#image img {
    position:relative;
    left:-400px;
    /*top: 230px;*/

    transition: all linear 500ms;
    -o-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 500ms;
}

#image img:target {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    /*top: 0px;*/
}

#image2
{
    height: 40px;
    width: 400px;   
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

    <header>
        <h1>CSS3 Image Slider</h1>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div id="image">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="image1" src="http://flickholdr.com/400/250/tree.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#image1">
                <img id="image2" src="http://flickholdr.com/400/250/flower.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
    <section>

    <footer>
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is going to be tough to solve without js. The browser scrolls the overflown div and *then* applies the transition. See http://jsfiddle.net/NWcXW/

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I think I'll give up and use JS!

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work by using `padding-top` instead of just `top`: http://jsfiddle.net/lucylou/NWcXW/1/